# Error consulta sql en php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una consulta a la base de datos y quiero mostrar los resultados, pero me muestra el error `Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in` se supone que este error es por que la consulta está mal, pero he realizado un `echo` a la consulta y ejecutado en la base de datos y se ejecuta con normalidad. No se me ocurre que más puede ser, os dejo el fragmento de código:

```
echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.presupuesto WHERE ID_PRESUPUESTO = '".$_SESSION["id_presupuesto"]."' and DETALLE = 'Descripción mobiliario:'";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
                $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
                while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {

                    echo '
                        <label>Descripción mobiliario:</label><textarea cols="71" rows="10">'.$row["CONCEPTO"].'</textarea>
                        <br><br><label>Importe:</label><input type="text" class="importe_Mobiliario" value="'.$row["IMPORTE"].'"><br>
                        ';
                }
```

La conexión a la base de datos es:

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Gestion", "UID"=>"admin", "PWD"=>"1234");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Con la comprobación con un if, aparentemente sale conectado y no da error.

Comment: Pon tu conexion a la BD, para ver como lo tienes.

Comment: Comprueba que no hay fallos en tu conexion con `if( $conn === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
`

Comment: Comprobado, no muestra error alguno

Comment: No he trabajado PHP directamente con SQL/SERVER solo con MYSQL, pero trata de cambiar tu *serverName* por `$serverName = "(local)\sqlexpress";` Por probar.

Comment: Probado y sigue igual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado, al final tras mucho debate y pelea, resulta que el error causado se debía a la tilde del parametro DETALLE. Con un `utf8_decode("Descripción mobiliario:");` se ha corregido todo. ¡Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

El error es muy simple. Usted esta pasando como parametro el resultado de

```
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
```

Lo cual es incorrecto, ya que esta funcion devuelve `true` o `false`.

Una vez preparada su consulta y ejecutado su query, para obtener los resultados deberia hacerlo así:

```
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {

                echo '
                    <label>Descripción mobiliario:</label><textarea cols="71" rows="10">'.$row["CONCEPTO"].'</textarea>
                    <br><br><label>Importe:</label><input type="text" class="importe_Mobiliario" value="'.$row["IMPORTE"].'"><br>
                    ';
            }
```

Para ver si obtiene resultados de su query pruebe agregar lo siguiente:

```
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );

if ($row_count === false)
   echo "No se han obtenido resultados";
else
   echo $row_count;
```

Suerte!

Comment: El error desapareció, pero sigue sin mostrar nada el while, es como si no entrará

Comment: Para comprobar su resulset dentro del WHILE haga print_r($row) a ver si esta trayendo informacion de la base de datos.

Comment: Sigue sin mostrar nada.

Comment: Su problema esta en su query. Haga print_r($sql), copie esa cadena y ejecutela dentro su DBMS

Comment: En mi DBMS se ejecuta la query imprimida con normalidad.

Comment: Haga print entonces de su variable $conn, y verifique que no sea nula y los datos de su conexion como el nombre de la base de datos, tabla, usuario, etc. Pruebe tambien agregar el nombre de la base de datos en su query: Ejemplo: SELECT * FROM nombreDeBase.dbo.presupuesto

Comment: El print de la variable $conn es el siguiente: Resource id #2

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta. Revise.

Comment: Añadido el nombre de la base de datos y comprobado los demás campos y nada

Answer (score 0):

Propongo que en lugar de   sqlsrv_prepare, utilices sqlsrv_query pues no mandarías parámetros.
Quedaría así:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.presupuesto WHERE ID_PRESUPUESTO = 
        '".$_SESSION["id_presupuesto"]."'and DETALLE = 'Descripción mobiliario:'";

 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
 // $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt); No la necesitarías
 if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }

$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );

  if ($row_count === false)
    echo "La consulta no produjo resultados.";
  else
    echo $row_count;

 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<label>Descripción mobiliario:</label><textarea cols="71" 
        rows="10">'.$row["CONCEPTO"].'</textarea><br><br><label>
        Importe:</label><input type="text" class="importe_Mobiliario" 
        value="'.$row["IMPORTE"].'"><br>';
        }
 sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, con esto el error al igual que la solución de más arriba se soluciona, pero tampoco muestra resultados.

Comment: Sino te muestra nada es porque no encuentra resultados la consulta

Comment: Aparentemente dice eso, pero en mi DBMS, el resultado es mostrado con la query, por eso no tiene sentido

Comment: ¿La columna CONCEPTO e IMPORTE pertenecen a la tabla presupuesto?

Comment: Si, de echo puedo ver los resultados en el DBMS

Comment: Activa los errores al principio de tu script php así: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101518/discussion-between-edgard-and-lorenzo).